# Increase Firefox tabs in Plasma 5 on high DPI laptop with small screen

Tags: fedora, firefox, display-settings, plasma5, appearance

In order to increase size I have used larger fonts (beside some other settings like toolbar icons size in Dolphin) and a global scale of 112%.

[image]

This is how my panel looks for me to be comfortable with it. But Firefox tabs are too small.

[image]

The fonts are OK, fallowing the system settings for font size, but tabs and buttons are not ok, global scaling seems to have no effect...

This is on Fedora 34 KDE with Plasma 5.21 - KDE Frameworks 5.80.

Comment: Ask here please https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - Did that [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/n3yfs6/how_to_increase_firefox_tabs_and_buttons_size_in/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than I thought. Found the answer [here](https://winaero.com/enable-hidpi-scaling-firefox/).

Go to advanced preferences (`about:config`), search for `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`.

> By default, its value data is set to -1.0, which means "follow the
> system settings". You can override it by changing the value to a
> positive number. Start changing it with 1.5 and continue until you
> satisfied with what you see.

In my case 1.4 was enough.